# Hibernate enum mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, enums

I need to map the enums which didn't implement the interface beforehand to the existing database, which stores enums in the same table as the owner class using the `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`.

```
class A {
    HasName name;
}

interface HasName {
    String getName();
}

enum X implements HasName {
    John, Mary;

    public String getName() { return this.name(); }
}

enum Y implements HasName {
    Tom, Ann;

    public String getName() { return this.name(); }
}
```

How the mapping should be handled in this case? Persisting to the database doesn't change as all of the enums implementing the interface will have different values, but I'm not sure how the objects should be retrieved from the DB (do I need a custom mapper, which will try to instantiate an enum using the specified enum classes? Does Hibernate natively support this functionality?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to create a custom `UserType` (e.g. [this one](http://pastebin.com/f39d77565)) and use it from your mappings

```xml
<property name="type" not-null="true">
  <type name="at.molindo.util.hibernate.EnumUserType">
    <param name="enumClass">
      com.example.MyEnum
    </param>
  </type>
</property>
```

EDIT: Hibernate comes with it's own EnumType (since 3.2 in hibernate-annotations, since 3.6 in hibernate-core - didn't know about it being in hibernate-annotations at the time of writing, but see [Diego's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604286/178526)).

Comment: In my case I don't know what the class of the enum will be. When instantiating `A`, Hibernate will need to pick one of the {X, Y} enums.

Comment: It shouldn't be to difficult to tweak the example UserType implementation to your needs. For instance, instead of storing the value only, you might also store the class (e.g. com.example.X.John or X.John, but than you'll need a mapping from X to com.example.X)

Comment: Means I need a custom mapper (didn't see your link to pastebin). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 50):

Hibernate provides `org.hibernate.type.EnumType` to map Enumerated types. For instance,

```
package com.igalia.enumerates;

public enum Status {
   BUSY,
   AVAILABLE;
}

package com.igalia.entities;

class MyClass {
   private Status status;
}
```

Then, do your Hibernate mapping as follows:

```xml
<class name="MyClass">
   <id name="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
   </id>

   <property name="status">
      <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
         <param name="enumClass">com.igalia.enumerates.Status</param>
      </type>
   </property>
</class>
```

And that's it. If you prefer to use JPA annotations instead of hbm.xml, use @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING). Check it here:

[Enumerations in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417062/enumerations-in-hibernate)

Comment: How do you set a default value for that? I added the following element to <property name="status"> but that didn't work for me: <column name="STATUS" not-null="true" default="com.igalia.enumerates.Status.BUSY" />

Comment: @valmar you can initialize *status* at class level (or doing it in its constructor). For instance, 'private Status status = Status.BUSY;'