# How can I convert a Hibernate String column to an Enum?

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, types

I currently have a simple String field in a Hibernate persisted class:

```
 private String font = "Times New Roman";
```

"Times New Roman" is the default value, so many stored objects have that data.  For several reasons, I would like to convert this to an Enum:

```
 @Enumerated(EnumType.String)
 private FontEnum font = FontEnum.TIMES;
```

Hibernate uses Enum.valueOf(clazz, string) to convert the column data, which would fail on "Times New Roman" due to the spaces.

Googling suggests overriding Enum.valueOf() is impossible; do others know differently?  Can I fool Enum.valueOf() to convert "Times New Roman" to FontEnum.TIMES?

Or, can I create a custom Hibernate converter like:

```
 public FontEnum legacyConverter(String old);
```

and add

```
 @Enumerated(EnumType.String)
 @Converter(Converters.legacyConverter()) // Does this exist?
 private FontEnum font = FontEnum.TIMES;
```

to my fields?  I haven't seen anything like that.

I know a fallback method would be to add some pre-persist logic that slowly migrates the data to another column, but I'd like to avoid that.

Thank you - it's my first question on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [EnumUserType](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Java5EnumUserType), see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/417062/664080).

Comment: It took me a bit to see how this would be used.  The implementation is here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-property  A custom UserType can be applied to a field and is, essentially, that converter I was looking for.