# Hibernate Exception - Unknown name value

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I have similar problem like this [[Hibernate Exception: Unknown name value for enum class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493590/hibernate-exception-unknown-name-value-for-enum-class])

But in my case,

```
Unable to filter, so returning non filtered results.Unknown name value for enum class com.xxxx.enums.Status: DELIVERED
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value for enum class com.xxxx.enums.Status: DELIVERED
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:104)


@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status", length = 10)
@AuditableField
private Status status;

public enum ReleaseStatus {
     DL("Delivered"),
}
```

Everything seems fine, still I am getting that exception.

Comment: Could it be that your enum field is called `DL` and not `DELIVERED`?

Comment: @beerbajay, if you look at the other so post, no issue with being defined as 'DL'

Comment: I mean that there's a mismatch between the two names. Just try it.

Comment: @beerbajay, not possible :( as some other dependencies on that enum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the String `DELIVERED` in your table. And this string is supposed to be the `name()` of one of the `ReleaseStatus` instances. And `ReleaseStatus` doesn't have any instance named DELIVERED. The only one you posted is named `DL`.

So what should be in the table is `DL` not `DELIVERED`. Or you should rename your enum instance to `DELIVERED`, to match what is stored in the database table.

You could define a custom Hibernate user type and use it for this enum as well, so that when getting "DELIVERED" from the database, Hibernate finds the enum instance constructed with this value (and ignoring the case). But storing the correct value from the start looks like a betteridea to me.

Answer (score 10):

I prefer defining a custom converter like:

```
    @Column
    @Convert(converter = StatusFirmaDocumentoConverter.class)  <<<<< :)
    @AuditableField
    private Status status;
```

(note: do *not* include the `@Enumerated` attribute) and creating a converter to process the enumerator value like:

```
public class CustomConverter implements AttributeConverter<Status, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Status attribute) {
        return attribute.getValue() ;
    }

    @Override
    public Status convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return  StatusFirmaDocumento.fromString(dbData);
    }

}
```

yeah, it's a shame that you can't tell to hibernate "translate *DL* to *DELIVERED*" and viceversa

Comment: Might be useful for someone else, but I left the Enumerated with the Convert and hibernate ignored the converter. Make sure to only have the Convert!