# Case insensitive Enum-Mapping with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, mapping

I got an entity with a column *state*. States stored in the DB are active and inactive (and some more). I wrote myself an enum like the following

```
public enum State {

    ACTIVE("active"), INACTIVE("inactive");

    private String state;

    private State(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

The entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_DB")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATE", nullable = false)
    private Integer state;

    // constructor, getter, setter

}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Unknown name value [active] for enum class [state]
```

Is it possible to do a case-insensitive hibernate-mapping to an enum?

Comment: why dont you use `ACTIVE("ACTIVE")` ???

Comment: Whatever u r doing is correct, show ur entity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493590/hibernate-exception-unknown-name-value-for-enum-class   check this

Comment: @Castilla: Because this won't help (see kosters answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map an enum as an ORDINAL or a STRING with hibernate annotations, for example:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private State state;
```

The ordinal mapping puts the ordinal position of the enum in the database. If you change the order of the enum values in your code this will conflict with existing database state. The string mapping puts the upper case name of the enum in the database. If you rename an enum value, you get the same problem.

If you want to define a custom mapping (like your code above) you can create an implementation of `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType` which explicitly maps the enum.

First I suggest some changes to your enum to make what follows possible:

```
public enum State {

    ACTIVE("active"), INACTIVE("inactive");

    private String stateName;

    private State(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }

    public State forStateName(String stateName) {
        for(State state : State.values()) {
            if (state.stateName().equals(stateName)) {
                return state;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown state name " + stateName);
    }

    public String stateName() {
        return stateName;
    }
}
```

And here is a simple (!) implementation of UserType:

```
public class StateUserType implements UserType {   

    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = {Types.VARCHAR}; 

    public int[] sqlTypes() {   
        return SQL_TYPES;   
    }   

    public Class returnedClass() {   
        return State.class;   
    }   

    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {   
        String stateName = resultSet.getString(names[0]);   
        State result = null;   
        if (!resultSet.wasNull()) {   
            result = State.forStateName(stateName);
        }   
        return result;   
    }   

    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {   
        if (null == value) {   
            preparedStatement.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);   
        } else {   
            preparedStatement.setString(index, ((State)value).stateName());   
        }   
    }   

    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException{   
        return value;   
    }   

    public boolean isMutable() {   
        return false;   
    }   

    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException    
         return cached;  
    }   

    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {   
        return (Serializable)value;   
    }   

    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {   
        return original;   
    }   

    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {   
        return x.hashCode();   
    }   

    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {   
        if (x == y) {
            return true;
        }   
        if (null == x || null == y) {   
            return false;
        }
        return x.equals(y);   
    }   
}
```

Then the mapping would become:

```
@Type(type="foo.bar.StateUserType")
private State state;
```

For another example of how to implement UserType, see: http://www.gabiaxel.com/2011/01/better-enum-mapping-with-hibernate.html

Comment: I think i would rather use no enumeration for the Entity then. This looks like a overhead and increasement in complexity to me, considering i just need the uppercase string of an entry in the db.

Comment: If you use the default EnumType.STRING annotation you get the uppercase enum name in the database. This is the most used solution I have come across. You don't need any private field or extra methods in your enum for that because enums expose a public String name() method by default.

Comment: I know, what do you want to tell my with that? Your solution might work, but I think that it is better to work without @Enumerated then, and just use the String for the entity instead of the enum.

Comment: I think it is cleaner to use a State field than a String field in your entity and there is good support for doing so in Hibernate.

Comment: Good support? The StateUserType raises the complexity of the code. I rather think there should be something like @Enumeration(Mode = EnumVale.IGNORE_CASE).

Comment: There are two reasonable default mappings and there is an option to roll your own (which is more work). I consider that reasonably good support. If you don't like it you should become a contributor to an open source project and implement a better solution.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing with similar problem and found simple answer.

You can do something like:

```java
@Column(name = "my_type")
@ColumnTransformer(read = "UPPER(my_type)", write = "LOWER(?)")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private MyType type;
```

(you don't need for "write" in `@ColumnTransformer` - for me it's for back compatibility, because my rows only in lower case. Without `write` Hibernate will write enum in same case, as in code in enum constant)

Comment: or also you can use JPA Attribute Converters

Comment: Does "UPPER(my_type)" has performance impact on queries like "SELECT t FROM MyType t WHERE t.type = :someParameter"?

Comment: @DimaG. mostly no, but sometimes yes. If you have an index on this "type" column, then this index couldn't be used in your query. But you can fix it by creating index like "create index upper_type on my_table (UPPER(type))" and will do the case-insensitive search. Or if you don't need case-insensitiveness, write native-sql :)