# How to embed another entity in a Hibernate entity using its id?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-key-relationship

Say I have a `Role` type, which contains a `long id`, `String name`, etc. And I have another `User` class. Each user will have a `roleId` column which will point to `Role.id`.

In my database I will 2 tables, one for user, the other for role. The `roleId` in the user table will be a foreign key to `role.id` table.

My question is, how can I map this in Hibernate, so that I'll be able to have a `Role role` column in my `User` class, and would be able to do things like `user.getRole().getName()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association):

> Many-to-one associations are declared at the property level with the
>   annotation @ManyToOne:

```
 @Entity
 public class User {
     @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
     @JoinColumn(name="roleId")
     public Role getRole() {
         return role;
     }
     ...
 }
```

> The @JoinColumn attribute is optional, the default value(s) is like in one to one, the concatenation of the name
>   of the relationship in the owner side, _ (underscore), and the name of
>   the primary key column in the owned side. In this example company_id
>   because the property name is company and the column id of Company is
>   id.

Comment: in this case, where i have multiple roles, but each user will only have 1 role at a time, am i looking at ManyToOne or ManyToMany ?

Comment: @ManyToOne.  You pretty much answered yourself :)

Comment: yeah, i realized that at the end but had typed the comment by then :). any chance you could look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971272/how-to-save-enum-value-to-db-with-hibernate?rq=1

Comment: The answers there look good.  Also check out the linked possible duplicate question.

Comment: Sorry, I linked to the wrong question. Here's what I had meant for you to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042903/how-to-use-enum-members-in-a-hibernate-entity-class

Comment: Question. If I have one table called `user`, and another called `user_inbox`, where I have a list of messages, each message has a `userId` column which refers to the `user.id` column. In that case, how would I map that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare yor fields as related entities so your `User` class would have `private Role role` field or limilar, annotated with proper `@OneToX` annotation.